# assign an action to web link UIDataDetectorTypeLink

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have used `UIDataDetectorTypeLink` to indicate that a string is a link. Tapping it inside my view works fine - it opens the URL in Safari

**My question is; is it possible to prevent iOS from opening the URL, so that I can pop-up a dialog to warn the user that they are about to leave my app?**

CURRENT BEHAVIOUR: 
tap link `-->` opens link in Safari

DESIRED BEHAVIOUR: 
tap link `-->` prompt the user and ask them if they want to leave the app
YES `-->` open safari
NO `-->` stay in app

The reason I am trying to do this is that I think it is nicer in terms of UI behaviour, but you could argue that since the link is clearly a link, the user should know that they are about to leave the app